# How do you print variables?

Tags: java, variables

So I am working with this code but the end result should look something like this.

EX.
People: 4
Pizza: 1
Cost: $14.95

My code looks like this -

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pizza {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);   
  int people = keyboard.nextInt();
  int pizza = people * 2 / 12 + 1;
  double cost = pizza * 14.95;

  System.out.println("People: "  + people +  "Pizzas: "  + pizza +  "Cost: $" + cost +  );
  }
}
```

The int people = keyboard.nextInt(); line allows me to input a integer value of people and the program then will take people * 2 and then divide by 12 (for the number of slices in a pizza) and + 1 to give me the pizzas I need. The cost will then be the pizza number * 14.95. I want the amount of people, pizzas, and cost to be displayed in the System.out.println method on the bottom. I do not know what I did wrong?  Shouldn't + people + display the people in that line? Same with  + pizza + and + cost + ?

Comment: The last **+** sign(After cost) in the `System.out.println()` code is probably causing an error in the code. Can you edit it and try again ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please tell us what error do you have. Can you compile your code? Your code output something?

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator joins strings (and other variables converted to strings). Just like in maths, you write it between two elements, so the final `+` was superfluous (and erroneous).

```
System.out.println("People: " + people + " Pizzas: " + pizza + " Cost: $" + cost);
```

When learning Java, you might want to use an IDE, which would point out this mistake for you, or just read the errors the compiler gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have that last `+` at the end of your print statement, since there's nothing after it. When it's removed your code seems to run fine, albeit with a slight whitespace issue which you can fix by adding spaces to the print statement.

```
12
People: 12Pizzas: 3Cost: $44.849999999999994
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("People: "  + people +  "Pizzas: "  + pizza +  "Cost: $" + cost +  );
```

You have put extra + at the end. Remove that.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation like `str1 + str2` is OK, but pay attention to correctly print `double` value: you need only two fractional digits:

```
try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    int people = keyboard.nextInt();
    int pizza = people * 2 / 12 + 1;
    double cost = pizza * 14.95;
    System.out.printf(Locale.US, "People: %d, Pizzas: %d, Cost: $%.2f\n", people, pizza, cost);
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
People: 10, Pizzas: 2, Cost: $29.90
```